# Python: preserving leading zeros from in a string

Tags: python, leading-zero

I have a JSON content to convert into an XML file with Python.

My problem is that every string starting with leading zeros is printed out with no zeros.

Heres a snippet of my JSON source file.

```
[
  { "virtuemart_product_id": 1001,
    "product_name": "Grüne Olivenpaste Arbequina",
     "product_sku": "000053", 
     "product_params": ... 
  }
]
```

If I run this code:

```
import json

with open('Data.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

for item in data:
  print(str(item['product_sku']))
  # code to print out XML...
```

**product_sku** loses the leading zeros and is shown as 53. This is a problem because the exact name must match the name of an image.

Why there are no zeros? It's a string, not an integer.

Comment: the full syntax is of `json-load` is `json.load(fp, *, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None, parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw)` (see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.load). Can you try to pass the option `parse_int=None` explicitly? Maybe you have some config that changes this default.

Comment: If the entry in `item['product_sku']` is a string, then why are you wrapping it in `str()` to print it? also you code has typos in it (it is missing a closing `]` for one. You should edit this to ensure a runnable example for people to investigate.

Comment: I replicated your example and it prints a string "00053"

Comment: As a sanity check, could you print the `type` of `item['product_sku']`?

Comment: on my python console, I can't reproduce the problem : `import json` + `json.loads('{ "product_sku": "000053" }')['product_sku']`

Comment: I'll recommend to first _double-check_ the content of the file, maybe you have two file with this same name, and you are mixing them up. Try to use an absolute path to be certain.

Comment: @Pac0 No need to pass the params... now it works fine. I really don't know why.
The only thing I changed, as reported by GlennMackintosh, is removing  str() for item['product_sku']

Comment: , mm that's strange, I don't understand how `str` was the cause of the issue. If I add `str` around my test above, I still get '000053' as output on the console.

Comment: @GlennMackintosh
Thank you. No need to use str() as you told. 
Otherwise, there's no typo in my code, the json snippet is correct.

Comment: @Pac0 It's the only modification made to my code. It works now... I don't want to investigate more 